# Neutron star emition of light: Are photons somehow fighting against gravity while leaving the surface?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, doppler-effect, neutron-stars

When a source is receding from the reciever the wavelength is elongated as the light is emitted from a more and more distant point so a distant rotating galaxy has two differently coloured parts depending of the fact are its translation and rotation added together or subtracted.For a photon that is leaving the surface of a neutron star the wavelength is elongated seemingly by the fact the photon must fight against gravity near the surface although it has its intrinsic speed 'c'.How can all be explained by the theory of 'space-time curvature' and what are the arguments of the 'river flow' theory?

Comment: [Maybe relevant?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment)

Comment: @Charlie In case of gravitational doppler effect should it be for the photon to gain wavelength considering the surface not moving regarding it, a lose of photon velocity but not intrinsic....Something like someone rolls a ball in a train that is moving in opposite direction from the ball.....